# While adding values using ContentValues in android, the next put method overwrites already added value

Tags: android

```
public void addup(UserProfile profile)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("countrycode", profile.getCCode());
    values.put("deviceid",profile.getDID());
    values.put("devicename", profile.getDName());
    values.put("homeLoc",profile.getLat()+","+profile.getLong());
    values.put("mobile", profile.getMobileNum().toString());
    values.put("name",profile.getUName());
    values.put("password", profile.getPWD());
    values.put("uid", profile.getUID());
}
```

i have tried this but everytime while using put one index always gets replaced with the new value. i have tried using ContenValues(8) to set everything in right place but again the same happens. please help

Comment: What do you expect the `addup` method to do?

Comment: It is being used to add rows to the sqlite database. While using put the values get added to a certain and the some values are being added to the same index again replacing the old, hence not adding the old values to the columns in the database. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `addup` method is missing the final database insert statement. You should modify your `addup` method as I have done below. I assume that your table name is called `TABLE_DATA`.

```
public void addup(UserProfile profile) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("countrycode", profile.getCCode());
    values.put("deviceid",profile.getDID());
    values.put("devicename", profile.getDName());
    values.put("homeLoc",profile.getLat()+","+profile.getLong());
    values.put("mobile", profile.getMobileNum().toString());
    values.put("name",profile.getUName());
    values.put("password", profile.getPWD());
    values.put("uid", profile.getUID());

    /* insert row */
    long rowID = db.insert(TABLE_DATA, null, values);

}
```

Let me know if this helps.